# Fire and Forget method in Async Web Api hosted in OwinCommunicationListener

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, azure-service-fabric

Recently I can across a code that we are using and is working fine and for the life of me I cannot figure out why.

We have a web API hosted in a service fabric cluster that is hosted over OwinCommunicationListener.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> WebApiMethod(RequestObject request)
{
   string test;
   SomeObject obj;
   ....
   DoSomethingAsync(test, obj);
   return this.ActionContext.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { Status = "Success" });
}


private async Task DoSomethingAsync(string param1, SomeObject param2)
{
    .....
    await SomeOtherAsyncMethod();
    .....
}
```

As far as I understand it should be a race condition between the method completion of DoSomethingAsync and the request disposing off and should throw an TaskCancelledException or something if later completes early, but it never does.

I am expecting some error since the task DoSomething is not awaited and yet it completes its work everytime. If I add

```
await Task.Delay(10000);
```

then the API response almost instantaneously and after the 10 seconds rest of the code is executed. Shouldn't by that time the host thread should be disposed since the original call was a Fire-and-Forget (not awaited).

What am I missing here.

Comment: This is unclear to me. Why do you expect an exception from where?

Comment: Worth mentioning that fire and forget methods in ASP.Net are almost always a terrible idea. You should use a library that is built to handle this sort of thing, for example Hangfire. Or since you seem to be in Azure, you can leverage that, not 100% sure which the feature is called, may be WebJobs?

Comment: @fildor I am expecting an exception since I am not awaiting the the method DoSomethingAsync and still it somehow manages to complete its work everytime

Comment: @DavidG I am strictly against using the above code but I am unable to explain how this has been working all this time

Comment: I don't get why you would expect it to throw an exception? Imagine implementing that with AsyncHandles. Your start the AsyncOp which returns the AsyncHandle. You ignore the handle. Operation will complete while the starting thread is already out of scope ... so what?

Comment: Since your top level method `WebApiMethod` is async, I expect this to be a valid case. Do have a look at this [simple-talk page](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-framework/the-net-4-5-asyncawait-feature-in-promise-and-practice/) also.

Comment: There is really no reason to expect an exception. The involved, not awaited method does nothing with the request(as far as I can tell based on the code), and no cancellation token is passed so I do not get why you mention a `TaskCancelledException` as well. So it will just complete sometime in the background.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that ties request object with DoSomethingAsync. But even if you pass RequestObj reference right into DoSomethingAsync, the method will get completed with no problem as GC won't collect your RequestObj while you're referencing the object. Also, once async execution kicks off, it lives its own life meaning the callback might be completed on a different thread but the one that request-handling pipeline has been dispatched with.